# prevent quartz scheduler job to fire immediately

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Is there a way to prevent jobs from executing when the it is first registered? I can potentially have 100+ triggers under 1 job and I don't want all the triggers to get executed when the application server is rebooted.

We're storing the jobs/triggers in-memory and storing the info in our db. So when the app server is started, we register all the jobs/triggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pause your scheduler during reboot/bootstrap [API here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/org/quartz/core/QuartzScheduler.html#pauseAll(org.quartz.core.SchedulingContext)), providing you can trigger events when that happen

Then resume once bootstrapped.